# React changing ID in complex JSON object after fetch from API

Tags: reactjs, json, axios, setstate

I'm making a react application that gets its data from an API. The API returns a JSON string with a complex JSON, but the important part is the key "activeNodes". The value in this key is a list of 3 objects which looks like this:

[image: Image of an "Active Nodes" object in the API response]

The example added is the third "Active Nodes" object in the response.

I manually checked the response from the API. It returns a list of 3 "Active Nodes" objects, with the IDs 686, 687 and 709. This is also the IDs of the actual "Active Nodes" objects in the database.

Now, let's move to the frontend. This is a React application, which uses these presumably two important versions:

"react": "^17.0.2",
"axios": "^0.25.0"

The first thing we do is to use axios to run a GET request to the same URL as I previously tested manually.

When inspecting the returned data from the API in the browser, it all looks OK. I can see the "activeNodes" key, which consists of a list of 3 objects with IDs 686, 687 and 709.

Now, the first thing we do is to run this function right here:

[image: Image of function being called to get initial data]

After manually inspecting the data being received on this call, you would expect this console.log to show a JSON object containing the activeNodes key with a list of object with the IDs 686, 687 abd 709, right?

This is the logged "data" variable:

[image: Image of the data variable after initial call]

**The "id" for the first two activeNodes objects are now the same.** The first object with the key 686 is always changed to 687. No other piece of information is changed. Just the ID field.
And this is not just a problem with the console.
The next step is for me to add this to a const:

```
const [activeNodes, setActiveNodes] = useState([]);
```

I then set it like this:

```
setActiveNodes(initialData?.activeNodes);
```

I also have this `useEffect`:

```
useEffect(() => {
    console.log('Active Nodes update');   
    console.log(activeNodes);
},[activeNodes]);
```

The result from this console log of the `activeNodes` variable is updated to a list of 3 objects.

In the output of the variable, the IDs are 687, 687 and 709. So the error of the changed ID is persisting into the activeNodes variable.

Now another VERY strange thing.
I changed the code up a little in the `useEffect` to this:

```
useEffect(() => {
    console.log('Active Nodes update');   
    console.log(activeNodes);

    for(let i = 0; i < activeNodes.length; i++){
        console.log(activeNodes[i]);
        console.log(activeNodes[i].id);
    }
},[activeNodes]);
```

Which in turn gave us this result in the browser:

[image: Each separate line of the active nodes list, and their IDs]

So when inspecting each line individually, the correct IDs show up.

Now in a later stage, I'm trying to use the `activeNodes.find()` function to find the node with id 686.
It is not found, and the function returns undefined.
I then looped through the `activeNodes` again, and could not find the ID 686. The ID 687 now showed up twice.

I'm really at a loss on this one.

Another VERY interesting thing is that the problem disappears, and the nodes are stored as 686, 687 and 709 **if I go to the API and remove the keys `availableFields`, `availableRelatedNodes` and `availableMeatballs`**.
This makes even less sense to me.
Any help or ideas is greatly appreciated. I've been stuck on this one for days.
I'll provide whatever you want of logs, tests, whatever.

I tried manipulating the IDs directly by saying:

```
activeNodes[0].id = 999;
```

But this didn't work either.

Comment: When logging out data structure, I suggest you convert them to a JSON string. Consoles have a bad habit of showing you live versions of object references. Eg `console.log("Active Node update", JSON.stringify(activeNodes, null, 2))`

Comment: I suspect some other code you haven't shown is manipulating the array data and changing the `id` property of one or some of the objects